# is it possible to reuse appdelegate in applicationDidFinishLaunching?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser, xml-parsing, uiapplicationdelegate

I am developing a **tab bar application.**

I have five tabs in it.

For each tab i have separate navigation controller.

For each tab's table View I want to load data from a web service.

I can do so for one tab by making a separate **xmlparser** class initializing it with **appdelegate** then call it in the **applicationDidFinishLaunching** .

I Can't do so for other tabs . I think that appdelegate conflicts or is it something else is the problem or any other solution .

Comment: Based on the wording of your question, it sounds like you want to construct an xml parser in your app delegate, and setting the parser and/or the app delegate as properties of multiple UINavigationController subclasses.  There's no reason this shouldn't work, so your problem probably has some other cause.  You might want to try describing your symptoms in more detail and posting some code.

Comment: Thanks for your precious advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new appdelegate;

```
MyAppdelegate *appDelegate = (MyAppdelegate*)[[UIAplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

and call applicationDidFinishLaunching.